# Why button not function when want to submit form in multiple tabs?

Tags: php

I want to submit my form in multiple tab using only one button but it is not working.I already put the button inside the form but it is also not working.Can I know what the solution to this problem?

```
<form method="POST"> 
<ul class="tab"> 
<li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onClick="openCity(event, 'diagnosis')">DOCTOR'S DIAGNOSIS</a></li> 
<li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onClick="openCity(event, 'others')">OTHERS</a></li> 
</ul> 
<div id="diagnosis" class="tabcontent">Tarikh Penilaian : <input id="test_Date" name ="test_Date" type="date"></div> 
<div id="others" class="tabcontent">Masa Penilaian : <input id="test_time" name ="test_time"></div> 
<div><button type="submit" name="btn_reg" id="btn_reg"></button></div> </form>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Did you try to add target attributes in your form?

Comment: <form  method="POST">
    <ul class="tab">
      <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onClick="openCity(event, 'diagnosis')">DOCTOR'S DIAGNOSIS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onClick="openCity(event, 'others')">OTHERS</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="diagnosis" class="tabcontent">Tarikh Penilaian : <input id="test_Date" name ="test_Date" type="date"></div>
    <div id="others" class="tabcontent">Masa Penilaian : <input id="test_time" name ="test_time"></div> 
    <div><button type="submit" name="btn_reg" id="btn_reg"></button></div>
  </form>

Comment: yes, i want to save it into database.